# No user records in Firebase authentication with Google sign in

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

It shows successful when I login via google account but there's no any user records in my firebase.

```
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if(result.isSuccess()){
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
                Toast.makeText(this,"Sign in with Google successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(this,"Sign in with Google failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount idToken) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(String.valueOf(idToken), null);
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"load into database successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

I thought firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential) will cause users' data save into the list?

[Image Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odFAn.png)

Comment: "no any user records in my firebase" and "users' data save into the list" Can you explain or show what you mean here? Where do you expect to see the user show up after signing them in to Firebase?

Comment: What is that "list" that you are talking about?

Comment: I have added the image description about what I mean for "list". I searched for it and others said if someone sign in using google account, it'll show something like google icon in provider areas but mine one shows nothing hmm